Sign Then Submit with CIP-30
Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this.
I am building a transaction using lucid on my backend and returning it to the client. The client is then supposed to sign and submit the transaction using a CIP-30 connection.
Backend:
>   const tx = await lucid.newTx()
>         .payToAddress(request.data.to, request.data.value)
>         .complete();
> 
>     return {
>         tx: tx.toString() // toString converts to cbor hex
>     }

On my front end I can successfully prompt the user for a signature and get back a witness set using CIP-30's signTx method. This witness set is also in cbor hex.
My issue is that I don't know how to call CIP-30's submitTx method. How do I put the cbor of the transaction body together with the cbor of the witness set to get a single cbor string I can use to call submitTx?
My client is React.js with TypeScript. The backend is a node.js environment.
Thanks again!

Figured it out. I now send my unsigned tx to the client in two forms:

const tx = await lucid.newTx()
  .payToAddress(request.data.to, request.data.value)
  .complete();

const altFormat = toHex(tx.txComplete.body().to_bytes())

return {
        tx: tx.toString(),
        altFormat: altFormat,
}


Then on the client side I sign the .tx value but use the altFormat value to construct the final transaction:

const witnesses = await wallet.signTx(txResult.data.tx);

const witnessSet = C.TransactionWitnessSet.from_bytes(fromHex(witnesses))

const txBody = C.TransactionBody.from_bytes(fromHex(txResult.data.altFormat))

const signedTx = C.Transaction.new(
    txBody,
    witnessSet,
    undefined
)

const result = await wallet.submitTx(toHex(signedTx.to_bytes()));


